# How to ignore hidden text during PDF text extraction

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

The linked [PDF](https://app.box.com/s/6tznpkf3u7t81dsui5852qqun0lw0dpl) has text that is hidden in some manner, however when I try to extract a particular region I get all the visible and invisible text.  I only want the visible text.  Any suggestions?

I'm using iTextSharp v5.5.7.

Code Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pdffn = args[0];
    //Hard coded coordinates specific to the linked PDF
    float llx = 664.0f;
    float lly = 1512.0f - 1472.0f;
    float urx = 890.0f;
    float ury = 1512.0f - 1277.0f;
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle r = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);
    string TextInRect = GetParagraphByRectangle(pdffn, 1, r);
}

/// <summary>
///This extracts text in a given rectangle of the PDF.  Could be handy to extract text in an event.
///This rectangle is execpted to be llx, lly, urx, ury
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pdffn"></param>
/// <param name="pageno"></param>
/// <param name="rect"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string GetParagraphByRectangle(string pdffn, int pageno, iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdffn);
    RenderFilter[] renderFilter = new RenderFilter[1];
    renderFilter[0] = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
    ITextExtractionStrategy textExtractionStrategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), renderFilter);
    string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageno, textExtractionStrategy);
    return text;
}
```

I have traced through the code and inspected the TextRenderInfo object when RenderText() is called but I did not find any clue that indicated whether text was somehow masked so that it is not visible.

Comment: There are many, many ways to hide text. What "some manner" are you trying to catch?

Comment: *inspected the `TextRenderInfo` object* - this object has only limited information, it only knows how and where text is to be drawn at the time when the drawing operation is executed. While it knows the colors used to fill or stroke the letter outlines, it does *not* know whether the background has been painted in the same color before or will be later on. Neither does it know whether it will later on be covered by some other drawing. As @Jongware said, there are many ways some text, even if visible to start with, can be invisible in the end.

Comment: @Jongware I'm trying to extract only the text that's visible when you open and view the PDF.

Comment: @mkl Is there another object that I can inspect that would give me a hint of what's visible or are you saying the only way to figure this out is to do a full page render and then figure it out using that?

Comment: At the top of your PDF is some text that can be selected and copied. Its size is normal (12 pts), and the text color is not white or transparent (it's kind of rich gray), so there is either a mask on the entire page, or some other object on top of the text. That's already 4 different ways of 'hiding' text. There are more than these, and you have to check *all* of them. For *all* text on that page.

Comment: @Darren Yes, to generically test whether your text is visible, you have to do something akin to rendering. If, on the other hand, you have a more specialized use case (e.g. you know that your text may only be hidden due to some covering bitmap, the task becomes much simpler

Comment: For anyone trying to do the same thing as I was am, I learned that PDFLib TET 5 knows how to honor clipping when extracting text and gives me the exact result I was looking for.  I'd love to do this with iTextSharp but have not been able to find a way to do it.